# remove reference to wstring after insertion to vector

Tags: c++, wstring

I have a vector that accepts LPCTSTR and have inserted a value by reference to wstring (ws1). The problem is every time ws1 changes its value, previously inserted values to vector also changes. Any advise how to remove reference to ws1 after insertion to vector?

```
const char* attributeoffile = file->Attribute("Method");

vecFileConsolidateParams.push_back(FILECONSOLIDATEPARAMS());
size_t size = strlen(attributeoffile)+1;
std::wstring ws1;
ws1.resize(size, L'\0');
#pragma warning (disable : 4996 )
std::mbstowcs(&ws1[0], attributeoffile, size);
vecFileConsolidateParams[count].filemethod = &ws1[0] ;
```

Comment: You insert _pointers_ into the vector. So if a string pointed by one of theses pointers changes it changes, what do you expect?

Comment: If you want to save previous value, insert a copy not reference

Comment: "I have a vector that accepts LPCTSTR" - don't tell in English what's better shown in C++. Also, we're missing `FILECONSOLIDATEPARAMS` and that function is suspect too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got it fixed. Used new operator, wmemset and wmemcpy.

```
TCHAR *tc0 = new TCHAR[size0];
tc0[size0] = { L'\0' };
wmemcpy(tc0, &ws0[0], size0);
.
.
.
vecFileConsolidateParams[count].filename = tc0;
delete [] tc0;
```

Comment: This looks awful. Just use `std::wstring` or Microsoft's `CString`.